# Disable time/date controls

Tags: css

Is there a way to hide/disable control options for `date` and `time` input's types that allow increment/decrement values by clicking on arrows.

```html
<input type='date' />
<input type='time' />
```

And at the same time have the possibility to provide data for each segment like `dd` from `dd/mm/yyyy` (basicly just hide the controls)

Like for example it's possible to set `resize: none` for textarea.

```css
textarea {
  resize: none;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<textarea />
```

Answer (score 5):

You can set the input to disabled, or use a `<input type="text" />` if those spinners are getting in your way

**EDIT**

I googled a little and it turns out it can be done on webkit browsers...
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/turn-off-number-input-spinners/

```css
input[type=date]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=date]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input[type=time]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=time]::-webkit-outer-spin-button
{ 
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
  margin: 0; 
}
```

```html
<input type='date'  />
<input type='time'  />
```

Comment: I do apologize that I forgot to mention, that the possibility to click on input segment like dd from dd/mm/yyyy and provide a value is pretty vital :)

Comment: I've edited my answer. Accept it if it solves your problem. Cheers :)

Answer (score 5):

At this stage, the short answer is that you can’t. The `date` and `time` elements aren’t widely supported yet, and any tweaking is, at this stage, still experimental.

There are good reasons to prefer the `date` and `time` types over the `text` type, but you won’t be able to control their appearance on all browsers reliably.

Chrome has some experimental styles: you can read about that at https://www.tjvantoll.com/2013/04/15/list-of-pseudo-elements-to-style-form-controls/. the `::-webkit-inner-spin-button` property may help.

Just remember that, at this stage, it is by no means universal.